# Dynamic access property named 'object'

Tags: c#

How to set/get the property 'object' of a dynamic object?

```
dynamic json = new ExpandoObject();

json.foo = "bar"; // OK
json.object = "content"; // Does not compile
json["object"] = "content"; // throw RuntimeBinderException
((IDictionary<string, object>)json)["object"] = "content"; // OK, but ...
```

I am trying to access a REST api, that require me to set a property named 'object'. The last solution actually fixes the problem, but I feel I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object` is C# keyword.
In order to define `object` property, you can tell compiler that "object" is a property name in that case, not keyword by using "@":

```
json.@object = "content";
```

It works for all keywords: `json.@foreach`, `json.@if`, `json.@var` etc.

However, it is strongly recommended to minimize its usage, since it worsens readability. If you want an `object` property in your output JSON, you could define a class for serialization and use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to tell serializer to serialize it as `object`:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public string ObjectContent { get;set; }
}
```

which will result into

```
{
  "object": "content"
}
```